# Input resistance of an inverter op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistance, input-impedance

I need to find the input resistance of this circuit. There are two parts of this exercise:

- The first one is to find the input resistance of the circuit without the capacitor.
- The second is to the find the input resistance of the circuit with the capacitor ( C = 10 nF.)

It is not mentioned if the op-amp is ideal or not.

Do i make it by finding the equivalent impedance of R3, R4, C and R5?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I need to find the input resistance of this circuit. Do I make it by finding the equivalent impedance of R3, R4, C and R5?*

It's slightly simpler than that. Because the -Vin input is a virtual ground, you can regard it as a short-circuit to ground and hence, R5 can be ignored. This then makes the input impedance: -

$$Z_{IN}\hspace{1cm}=\hspace{1cm}R_3 + X_C||R_4$$

This answer assumes an ideal op-amp.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I didn't understand why the -Vin input is a virtual ground. isn't it supposed to have a voltage because of vs?

Comment: It's voltage will be the same as +Vin and.... because +Vin is connected to ground via R1 and R2, -Vin also will be at ground. If you haven't learnt about the term "virtual ground" then maybe you should look it up. I'll try and leave a link @Aleat

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/617869/why-is-high-open-loop-gain-needed-for-an-op-amps-virtual-ground and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/632784/why-is-vop-in-my-circuit-not-zero

Comment: @Aleat [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Aleat, are we done now?

Comment: @Aleat, are we done now? This is the 3rd time I've prompted you on this matter.

Comment: Yes, i wasn’t being able to answer

Comment: Do you understand my answer; did you follow the concept of the virtual ground?

Comment: Yes, i understood everything.

Comment: You should consider accepting my answer --> [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) @Aleat

Comment: Why can we assume -ve input to be a short circuit to ground? I understand it has the same voltage as +ve due to virtual ground but per my understanding, +ve may not necessarily be at 0V due to R1 and R2.

Comment: @HFOrangefish because both resistors on the non-inverting input are grounding the pin.